# Read a particular value of JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : {
            "uuid" : "e606d53"
        }
}
```

I am trying to read UUID

```
$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
print_r($obj);
$UniID = $obj["result"]["uuid"];
echo $UniID;  ///result Blank
```

Comment: That should work, what does your print_r output?

Comment: Works fine when I test it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JimL the output is the same as i posted before.

Comment: @MDMalik your code working fine.

Comment: @MDMalik — "the output is the same as i posted before" — You mean `print_r` outputs *the raw JSON* and not something like `Array ( [success] => 1 [message] => [result] => Array ( [uuid] => e606d53 ) ) `?!

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON you included at the top of the question as input, the `print_r` statement will output this:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => e606d53
        )

)
```

But you said, in a comment:

> the output is the same as i posted before

The only way I can interpret this is that you mean the JSON you included at the top of the question is the result of the `print_r` statement.

This suggests that your JSON is double encoded.

i.e. that there was an associative array which was encoded as a JSON text. Then that JSON text was encoded as a JSON text.

Since it was encoded twice, you need to decode it twice:

```
<?php

$execResult = '"{\n    \"success\" : true,\n    \"message\" : \"\",\n    \"result\" : {\n            \"uuid\" : \"e606d53\"\n        }\n}"';
print "Original JSON\n\n";
print_r($execResult);


$decode_1 = json_decode($execResult, true);
print "\n\nDecoded once\n\n";
print_r($decode_1);

$decode_2 = json_decode($decode_1, true);
print "\n\nDecoded twice\n\n";
print_r($decode_2);


print "\n\$decode_2[\"result\"][\"uuid\"]\n\n";
$UniID = $decode_2["result"]["uuid"];
echo $UniID;  ///result Blank

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Original JSON

"{\n    \"success\" : true,\n    \"message\" : \"\",\n    \"result\" : {\n            \"uuid\" : \"e606d53\"\n        }\n}"

Decoded once

{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : {
            "uuid" : "e606d53"
        }
}

Decoded twice

Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => e606d53
        )

)

$decode_2["result"]["uuid"]

e606d53
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give it a try. It should work fine for your code.

```
$obj = json_decode($execResult); 
echo $obj->result->uuid;
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer, I'd suggest removing it as it will probably be downvoted

Comment: This is an alternative solution. Should I remove it?